# How do you use MYSQL in ColdFusion?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I'm currently learning ColdFusion and it's been going well except for when I have got to trying to use databases. I can't find anywhere what so ever how to connect to a MYSQL database. Can someone tell me how it's done?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised if you couldn't find anything on how to connect to a MySQL datasource.  Here's [Adobe's list of settings](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fe4.html) to use in CF Administrator.  The important part here is the name you give it.

Because then in your queries or stored procs, you use that name to reference the datasource:

```
<cfquery name="yourQuery" datasource="name of datasource">

<cfstoredproc procedure="yourProcedure" datasource="name of datasource">
```

Here's more links Google showed up:

- http://www.hosting.com/support/mysql/coldfusionstring/
- http://www.bluereef.net/support/extensions/database/mysql/coldfusion.html
- http://www.justskins.com/forums/how-to-connect-to-130869.html

Comment: So how would you see like a list of databases? is there nothing built in to ColdFusion like a phpmyadmin tool?

Comment: In your CF Administrator there is a page listing all your datasources. Not sure that's the same as what you're thinking of.

Comment: @davidbenjamin998 - In any language, datasources simply store connection settings. They are not specifically designed for administering databases (though you can access similar information by querying [database metadata](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html)). You need a different tool for that (mySQL Workbench, phpMyAdmin, etcetera)